# War deployment problem on tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, classpath, tomcat7

When I try to deploy and run the war file on tomcat 7 I got following error..

```
2011-04-15 16:53:42 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\oracle\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\oracle\ora10g\instantclient;C:\oracle\ora10g\bin;C:\oracle1\ora10g;C:\Perl\Bin;C:\Perl\5.8.1\Bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread;C:\Perl\5.8.1\Bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI Control Panel;C:\Program Files\WINZIP;C:\Program Files\WINZIP;C:\Program Files\Mono-1.2.5.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_14\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.6.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.0\bin;C:\Program Files\cvsnt;C:\Program Files\Windows Imaging\;C:\Program Files\YourKit Java Profiler 7.5.11\bin\win32;C:\Program Files\YourKit Java Profiler 9.5.4\bin\win32;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin;C:\CServer\lib\windows
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 3192 ms
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor webdatasinkserver.xml from C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf\Catalina\localhost
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
WARNING: A docBase C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\webdatasinkserver inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ncr.passport.webdatasink.servers.tomcat.dbcp.NcrDataSourceFactory]
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory host-manager
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory manager
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 15, 2011 4:53:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 13377 ms
ava:45)
    at com.ncr.passport.webdatasinkserver.web.datasink.server.model.ClientMonitoring.refresh(ClientMonitoring.java:125)
    at com.ncr.passport.webdatasinkserver.web.daemon.KeepAliveTask.doTask(KeepAliveTask.java:34)
    at com.ncr.passport.webdatasinkserver.web.daemon.DaemonTask.run(DaemonTask.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException
    at com.ncr.passport.cswe.receive.persist.hibernate.CSHibernateUtility.getSessionFactory(CSHibernateUtility.java:77)
    ... 10 more
```

error in stdout

```
["http-bio-8443"-exec-3][2011-04-15 17:13:50,840][FATAL][persist.hibernate.HibernateUtility] : Fatal Exception Occured: Method [static Initializer] Class [com.ncr.passport.persist.hibernate.HibernateUtility] Exception [org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not find datasource] org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:56)org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:366)org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:60)org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:1881)org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1174)com.ncr.passport.cswe.receive.persist.hibernate.CSHibernateUtility.getSessionFactory(CSHibernateUtility.java:114)com.ncr.passport.cswe.receive.persist.hibernate.CSHibernateUtility.currentSession(CSHibernateUtility.java:49)com.ncr.passport.cswe.receive.persist.hibernate.CSHibernatePersistenceManager.beginTransaction(CSHibernatePersistenceManager.java:69)com.ncr.passport.cswe.receive.persist.CSPersistenceManager.beginTransaction(CSPersistenceManager.java:15)com.ncr.passport.cswe.receive.persist.service.CSPersistServices.startService(CSPersistServices.java:67)com.ncr.passport.cswe.receive.itemprocessing.service.impl.DataSinkControlServicesImpl.findAll(DataSinkControlServicesImpl.java:71)com.ncr.passport.cswe.receive.itemprocessing.service.DataSinkControlServices.findAll(DataSinkControlServices.java:63)com.ncr.passport.webdatasinkserver.web.datasink.server.model.DataSinkServerControl.clear(DataSinkServerControl.java:178)com.ncr.passport.webdatasinkserver.web.datasink.server.servlets.DataServlet.init(DataServlet.java:224)javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1189)org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1103)org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:813)org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
["http-bio-8443"-exec-4][2011-04-15 17:14:20,965][FATAL][hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider] : Could not find datasource: java:/comp/env/jdbc/NCRSQLATMDS
javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ncr.passport.webdatasink.servers.tomcat.dbcp.NcrDataSourceFactory]
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:84)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:826)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:145)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:814)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:145)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:814)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:145)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:814)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:366)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:1881)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1174)
    at com.ncr.passport.cswe.receive.persist.hibernate.CSHibernateUtility.getSessionFactory(CSHibernateUtility.java:114)
    at com.ncr.passport.cswe.receive.persist.hibernate.CSHibernateUtility.currentSession(CSHibernateUtility.java:49)
    at com.ncr.passport.cswe.receive.persist.hibernate.CSHibernatePersistenceManager.beginTransaction(CSHibernatePersistenceManager.java:69)
    at com.ncr.passport.cswe.receive.persist.CSPersistenceManager.beginTransaction(CSPersistenceManager.java:15)
    at com.ncr.passport.cswe.receive.persist.service.CSPersistServices.startService(CSPersistServices.java:67)
    at com.ncr.passport.cswe.receive.itemprocessing.service.impl.DataSinkControlServicesImpl.findAll(DataSinkControlServicesImpl.java:71)
    at com.ncr.passport.cswe.receive.itemprocessing.service.DataSinkControlServices.findAll(DataSinkControlServices.java:63)
    at com.ncr.passport.webdatasinkserver.web.datasink.server.model.DataSinkServerControl.clear(DataSinkServerControl.java:178)
    at com.ncr.passport.webdatasinkserver.web.datasink.server.servlets.DataServlet.init(DataServlet.java:224)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:813)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ncr.passport.webdatasink.servers.tomcat.dbcp.NcrDataSourceFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:82)
```

The same application works properly on tomcat 6 without any modification..

When I deployed the war, tomcat 7 did not copy context file in to catlina/localhost so copied it manually but that also didnt help..
the classnotfounderror in the log is coming from the resource file.

my server.xml file has no other modification to default except 8080 and 8443 port open

Comment: I think I get the problem.. some missing jars.. let me check and confirm

Comment: Yes, the problem was missing jars in tomcat 7 lib directory.. after adding them problem solved. and no need to add context file to catlina/localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you solved the problem, I will explain why it happened - you had an installation that has some configurations and preconditions that were not met in the new installation.

That's why all .jar files needed for an application should be placed in `WEB-INF/lib`, unless completely necessary. Also, I usually commit my `server.xml` in the repository so that I know that modifications for a given environment (dev/production) have to be done before successfully running.